# Visa refusal for UK

Tags: uk

With the Reasons given on visa refusal, what need to be done on subsequent application[image]

Comment: Omo Naija, Who takes care of you in Ivory Coast? Provide that information and bank statements from them. However the truth is even if you do that you’re not going to get a visa. Unemployed young men (who are not students) from developing countries in Africa simply do not get approved for a visa without very serious extenuating circumstances, e.g. going to represent their country at some global tournament or going to receive some prestigious globally recognized award. Simply the facts.

Comment: Informations as regard parents and sponsor in relation to residency and financial competency were all supplied yet refused

Comment: sponsored applications are always weak: your parents and uncle aren't applying for a visa, you are

Comment: @nkjt Exactly. The third bullet point makes this clear.